# Reset Key Names to Defaults?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, foreign-key, ssms, primary-key

I'm working with some tables/columns that were renamed at some point, but the names of the primary/foreign keys are still based on the previous names.

In SSMS is there any (preferably automatic) way to reset the name of a key to what the default name would be if it were newly created?

Answer (score 7):

There's no way to do this automatically but you can query the catalogue views to find constraint names not in the desired pattern then generate the desired script that way.

Something like

```
DECLARE @Script NVARCHAR(MAX);

WITH FK
     AS (SELECT *,
                'FK_' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) + '_' + OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id)                  AS provisionalName,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parent_object_id, referenced_object_id ORDER BY create_date) - 1 AS RN
         FROM   sys.foreign_keys),
     Combined
     AS (SELECT name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT        AS name,
                OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id) AS schemaName,
                provisionalName + CASE
                                    WHEN RN = 0 THEN ''
                                    ELSE CAST(RN AS VARCHAR)
                                  END                AS provisionalName
         FROM   FK
         UNION ALL
         SELECT name,
                OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id)       AS schemaName,
                type + '_' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS provisionalName
         FROM   sys.key_constraints)
SELECT @Script = x.rename.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM   (SELECT 'exec sys.sp_rename ''' + QUOTENAME(schemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name) + ''', ''' + provisionalName + ''';
'
        FROM   Combined
        WHERE  provisionalName <> name
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) x(rename);

PRINT @Script;
--EXEC (@Script);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sp_rename` to change the names of constraints such as Foreign Keys.  The syntax is simple:

From the SQL Server documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx

```
exec sp_rename 'YourSchema.FK_OldName', 'FK_NewName';
```

Note that the schema *is required* when renaming constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sp_rename` systems stored procedure to change the name of the keys.

```
sp_rename 'dbo.PK_TableName_OldName', 'PK_TableName_NewName';
```

Comment: Do not specify the schema name in the new name or it will become part of the new object name.